# How to change background behind every word in text using just css?

Tags: css

I'm interested in styling quote with highlighting every word in it's text with background color. Problem with solid background is : no gaps within color. 
What may I do to get result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56CvI.jpg), but in case of every word highlighting?

Comment: hii... include html and css code

Comment: hi, i haven't a solution yet, the text would be random assumption from db on server, I have no idea about  what code I should include)

Comment: Another code service?

Comment: You can just use <span> to cover each line

Comment: I can brake line into the words array, put every one into the span tag - it would be easy, but is there pure css solution?

Comment: @ярославкорнилов Without knowing your HTML, no viable solution can be provided. You want pure css, but you haven't provided any HTML allowing the community to help you 100%. At this point it is guess work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background color on a single span within a paragraph that has a max width & line-height.

HTML:

```
<p>
  <span>If it scares you, it might be a good thing to try it.</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  line-height: 2;
  max-width: 100px;
}

p span {
    background: red;
}
```

Live example:
https://codepen.io/guidobouman/pen/rjaJap

Explanation:
A span is an inline element. Backgrounds on inline elements show only behind the actual line. When you make the line-height of the containing element larger, a space between the background appears.

Comment: But I'm still looking for something elegant like this for horizontal word aligment

Comment: That's not possible unfortunately. You'll need to split it up in different spans.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    <span>Hi</span> 
    <span>I</span>
    <span>am</span>
    <span>Naveed</span>
    <span>Ramzan</span>
</p>
<style>
    p span:nth-child(1){background: red;}
    p span:nth-child(2){background: blue;}
    p span:nth-child(3){background: black;}
    p span:nth-child(4){background: white;}
    p span:nth-child(5){background: orange;}
</style>
```

Try this one.

By the way, if you are using some scripting language like PHP or asp.net then you can set background color by using loop.

Comment: Problem is the assumption has random amount of words within, so I may automate the styling process

Comment: Oh, i see detail about php, but am I able to do it in solid css?

Comment: Maybe using Java script you can do this if you are not using PHP / asp.net

Comment: you need to change a way of child enumeration: nth-child(5n-4), nth-child(5n-3), nth-child(5n-2), nth-child(5n-1), nth-child(5n)